# Radio button not selected by default in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to make the radio button selected by default in angular 4.

Below is my template code:

```
 <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <label class="form-check-label">  </label>
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input"
    name="type"
    [(ngModel)]="searchForm.type"
    [value]="['all']"
[checked]='searchForm.type ==='all''
    > All
</div>
```

And I am initializing default value in my component ngOnInit

```
export class myComponent{
searchForm:FormVO = new FormVO();

ngOnInit(){
this.searchForm.type='all';
}
}
```

I also tried with constructor initialize, here actually value is setting to searchForm.type as all in both constructor or nginit way. 
Issue I am facing is I could not make the radio selected only in template.

These are the ways I tried:

Way 1:

```
[checked]="searchForm.type ==='all'"
```

Way 2:

```
[checked]="searchForm.type ==='all' ? true : false"
```

way 3:

```
[checked]="searchForm.type =='all'"
```

I also read in few sits like through numbers i can make this selected by default. I did not try that way, because I want the solution with string values only.

Thanks in advance.

I request to avoid marking this as duplicate question, as I already tried all the solutions for those questions and nothing worked.

I am using angular cli with angular 4.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding form tag around input boxes. Please try it and look if it works for you.

Comment: Yes, works. Are you also using multiple components, each including the radios, below each other? They seem to be interfering with each other. I am not sure this is intended

Answer (score 0):

The docs have a nice example how to use radio with Angular

https://angular.io/api/forms/RadioControlValueAccessor#how-to-use-radio-buttons-with-form-directives

> ```
> import {Component} from '@angular/core';
>
> @Component({
>   selector: 'example-app',
>   template: `
>     <form #f="ngForm">
>       <input type="radio" value="beef" name="food" [(ngModel)]="myFood"> Beef
>       <input type="radio" value="lamb" name="food" [(ngModel)]="myFood"> Lamb
>       <input type="radio" value="fish" name="food" [(ngModel)]="myFood"> Fish
>     </form>
>
>     <p>Form value: {{ f.value | json }}</p>  <!-- {food: 'lamb' } -->
>     <p>myFood value: {{ myFood }}</p>  <!-- 'lamb' -->
>   `,
> })
> export class RadioButtonComp {
>   myFood = 'lamb';
> }
> ```

The value from `value="..."` matching the value assigned to `myFood` will be selected (`'lamb'` in the example).

Comment: In my case [value]="'all'" already and trying to select that with [checked]="searchForm.type=='all'", what should be done here ?

Comment: Just get rid of `[checked]="searchForm.type=='all'"`

Comment: still no luck :(

Comment: Please add the code you currently have to your question.